# Pass Computed Property-like Binding to Ember.Object.create

Tags: ember.js

So I'm trying to mimic how components do one way bindings, but make them work just like Computed Properties. How would you do something like:

```
Parent = Ember.Object.extend({
  color: 'red',
  init: function() {
     this.set('child', Child.create({ parent: this, color: Ember.computed.alias('parent.color') }));
  }
});
Child = Ember.Object.extend({});

parent = Parent.create();

// returns AliasedProperty {altKey: "parent.color", _dependentKeys: Array(1)}...
// I want 'red' instead
parent.get('child.color');
```

So I know [bindings are depreciated](https://www.emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/#toc_ember-binding),
but I can't find another way for Ember 1.10.1. Also, [they are asynchronous](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10429), which I don't want.

The reason why I'm doing this is to have the Data Down Actions Up pattern between `Ember.Object`s, so I don't want `Child` to know what's happening in `Parent`. With this power, I can create two instances of `Child` with different bindings.

Thus, I want to define the binding/computed property on create. In other words, pass down Parent's properties to the Child, but binded on create.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: um, whats the problem with your code? Except the typos, like define `Child` before you use it, and you probably meant `Ember.computed.alias` instead `Ember.compute`. Also you should define the alias on the class, but in earlier ember versions it would also be possible during create, and I don't know it for `1.10`, so this might be valid. Also I hope you realize that Ember `1.10` is ancient!

Comment: updated the problem. sorry for the typo. updated the question. it `alias` isn't valid on create..... no idea for newer versions. would love some solution on create.

Comment: What do you mean by "mimic how components do one way bindings"?

Comment: I pasted your code into a Twiddle and it seems to be working. Might want to try updating Ember?

Comment: @locks I made a twiddle too. it seems like it's just the ember version..... didn't think Ember would change the behaviour. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `color: Ember.computed.alias('parent.color')` to the `.extend`:

```
Child = Ember.Object.extend({
  color: Ember.computed.alias('parent.color')
});
```

Later only set the parent when calling `.create`:

```
this.set('child', Child.create({ parent: this }));
```

And it will work as expected.

Comment: not exactly what i want, as this means that parent knows about child. i'm looking for something like how hbs components work `{{ child-component color=color}}` (child knows nothing about parent)